# Absolute Max and Min on a unit disk

Tags: calculus

How do you find the absolute max and min of $f(x,y)=2xy-(x^4)-(y^4)$ on the unit disk $x^2+y^2 ≤1$? I have tried multiple times and have gotten nowhere.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Maths SX!

**A suggestion**:

You can use polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
2xy-x^4-y^4&=2r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta -r^4(\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta) \\
&=r^2\sin2\theta-r^4(1-2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta)=r^2\Bigl(\sin2\theta-r^2+\frac{r^2}2\sin^22\theta\Bigr)\\
&=\frac{r^2 }2( r^2\sin^2\theta+2\sin2\theta-r)
\end{align}
and see the second factor as quadratic polynomial in $t=\sin 2\theta$, and search, in function of $r$ the extrema of the second factor, i.e. the extrema of the polynomial $\;f(t)=r^2t^2+2t-r$ when $t\in[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=r\cos t$ and $y=r \sin t$. Then, $r^2\le 1$ and $f(x,y) $ can be expressed as

$$f(r, t) = -r^4 +\frac12(r\sin 2t +1)^2 - \frac12$$

1) For a given $r$, $f(r,t)$ is minimal when $\sin 2t = -1$, i.e.

$$f_{min}(r)=-r^4 + \frac12 (1-r)^2 - \frac12$$

which is then minimized at $r= 1$, $f_{min}(1) = -\frac32$.

2) For a given $r$, $f(r,t)$ is maximal when $\sin 2t = 1$, i.e.

$$f_{max}(r)=-r^4 + \frac12 (1+r)^2 - \frac12$$

Take the derivative and set it to zero,
$$f_{max}'(r)=-4r^3 + r+ 1=0$$

which yields $r=0.761$ and in turn $f_{max}(0.761) = 0.715$.

So, the minimum and maximum values of $f(x,y)=2xy-(x^4)-(y^4)$ on the unit disk $x^2+y^2 ≤1$ are $-1.5$ and $0.715$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Lagrange method to find absolute minima and maxima in a given region

$$f(x,y)=2xy-x^4-y^4-\alpha(x^2+y^2-1) $$
Where the symbol $\alpha $ means a symbol of Lagrange 
Now we need to solve a system of equations
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=2y-4x^3-2x\alpha=0   
\\
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=2x-4y^3-2y\alpha=0
\\
x^2+y^2=1
\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$ 
now need to find $\alpha,x,y $
Note that the first 2 equations are symmetric (when replacing x with y, the system does not lose its meaning) $\Rightarrow $
Let $x=y $ 
Then for the first equation 
$$x-2x^3-\alpha x=0 $$ $$\Rightarrow $$
$x(1-2x^2-\alpha )=0) $ And $$x=0 ,2x^2=1-\alpha $$
$$\Rightarrow $$
$ \alpha =0 $ and we got special points $$(0,0),(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2}),(\frac{-1}{\sqrt2},\frac{-1}{\sqrt2})$$
It remains to substitute the obtained points in the final function
$$ f(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2})=\frac{1}{2} $$
of course we could lose the solution-type  $(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}) $
and $\frac{-1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2} $ 
Finally we have
$$ f(\frac{-1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2})=f(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{-1}{\sqrt2})=\frac{-3}{2} $$